# Negative exponential distribution formula

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If i have the following distribution:

$f_Y(y) = e^{-y}$

why is called a negative exponential distribution when  y > 0 ?

Comment: Presumably because of the $-y$ in $e^{-y}$.  I, and I think most other people, call it an *exponential distribution*

Comment: Yes i see that, but why when y > 0

Comment: $-y$ is negative only when $y$ is positive. [Negative binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) also have support on the positive integers and zero.